# html.actionlink dont call action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

iam new to MVC. after readings some part of manuals tried to create someting to pratice.

and now i need same help on a actionlink. he didnt call the action. but if i press a button he call the action and the value of the actionlink is there.

what i am trying to do is when i press the actionlink with text the letter in question in this case is "A". i call the action and he return a query result like names that start with "A" from a database. with the button works but not with the actionlink. maybe i am doing something wrong

here is my code.

```
<!-- Alfabeto -->
    <div class="alfabetofont">
        <span class="alfabetoborder">

            @Html.ActionLink("A", "CrewMembers", "Home",
                         new { id = "A", @Name = "A" }, new { @class = "alfabeto_link" })
```

In my controller. is this

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CrewMembers(Models.crew crew,string id,string Name)
        {
        if (crew.Nome != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = crew.GetStoreProc(crew.Nome);
            ViewData["TabelaTrip"] = dt;
            return View();
        }
        else return View();
        }
```

this action is the same as the button because  if add another action it give an error about ambigous with a action with the same name.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` generates a link, which makes GET, not a POST. Your need a `[HttpGet]` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ambiguous errors normally relate to a method with the same name and same parameters. The compiler cannot be sure which one to call.

If I understand your question correctly, you want several links which return the user to different search results based on the link they clicked. So the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("A", "CrewMembers", "Home",
                         new { @StartsWith = "A" }, new { @class = "alfabeto_link" })
```

Should have a relate [HttpGet] action related it like so

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CrewMembers(string StartsWith)
{
      //Do some fetch based on passed in string
      //Populate viewModel with data
      return view(viewModel)
}
```

Your post method should contain different parameters than your get method and will most likely only need to contain your viewmodel. This, however, depends entirely on what your post method is doing.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CrewMembers(Models.crew crew)
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. that help to fix. the httpget was giving me a white page (bad request) than i notice that existe already a httpget actionresult but with no parameters, just add to add the string startwith. now works fine. thanks again. cheers